# Relacionamento de Tabelas Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, entidade-relacionamento

Tenho um **banco** com o seguintes relacionamentos:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de trazer o relacionamento do `Menu` conforme o `Perfil` do usuario.

No tiker faço os seguintes passos:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(1);
$perfil = $user->perfil;
$itemMenu = $perfil->itemMenu;
```

Quando vou buscar o Menu, nao consigo

```
$menu = $itemMenu->menu;
```

Na minha classe `User.php`

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token'
    ];

    public function perfil()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Perfil','id_perfil');
    }
}
```

Na classe `Perfil`

```
class Perfil extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    protected $table = 'perfil';

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_perfil';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_perfil',
        'no_perfil'
    ];

    public function itemMenu()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ItemMenu', 'perfil_item_menu', 'id_perfil', 'id_item_menu');
    }    
}
```

Classe `Menu`

```
    class Menu extends Model implements Transformable
    {
        use TransformableTrait;

        protected $table = 'menu';

        /**
         * The primary key for the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $primaryKey = 'id_menu';

        protected $fillable = [
            'id_menu',
            'no_menu',
            'ic_menu'
        ];

        public function itemMenu()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ItemMenu', 'id_menu');
        }

        public function perfil()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Perfil', 'perfil_menu', 'id_menu', 'id_perfil');
        }
    }
```

Classe `ItemMenu`

```
class ItemMenu extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    protected $table = 'item_menu';

    /**
     * The primary key for the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_item_menu';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_item_menu',
        'id_menu',
        'no_item_menu'
    ];

    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu', 'id_menu');
    }

    public function perfil()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Perfil', 'perfil_item_menu', 'id_item_menu', 'id_perfil');
    }
}
```

Comment: em User qual é o nome do campo que se relaciona com perfil, no seu model não está descrito.

Comment: eu fiz uma resposta, quanto fizer interação verifique se está ok ou algum erro me avise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu refiz os relacionamentos, por ver que está faltando configurações e relacionamentos:

**`Menu`**

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id_menu";
    protected $fillable = array('no_menu','ic_menu');
    protected $table = "menu";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function itemMenu()
    {        
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ItemMenu', 'id_menu', 'id_menu');
    }    
}
```

**`ItemMenu`**

```
class ItemMenu extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id_item_menu";
    protected $fillable = array('id_menu','no_item_menu');
    protected $table = "item_menu";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function menu()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu', 'id_menu', 'id_menu');
    }

    public function perfil()
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Perfil',
                        'perfil_item_menu', 'id_item_menu', 'id_perfil');
    }
}
```

**`Perfil`**

```
class Perfil extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id_perfil";
    protected $fillable = array('no_perfil');
    protected $table = "perfil";
    public $timestamps = false; 

    public function itemMenu()
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ItemMenu','perfil_item_menu',
                                            'id_perfil','id_item_menu');
    }    
}
```

**`User`**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password','id_perfil'];

    protected $hidden = ['password','remember_token'];

    public function perfil()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Perfil',
                                              'id_perfil','id_perfil');
    }
}
```

***Depois para utilizar:***

```
$user     = App\Models\User::find(1);
$perfil   = $user->perfil();
$itemMenu = $perfil->itemMenu;
var_dump($itemMenu);
```