# Campos Adicionais no Modelo Pivot Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, pivot, laravel-6

Estou em meu primeiro projeto Framework Laravel e estou com dificuldade no relacionamento `N:M`, tenho a estrutura do banco de dados `fornecedor->fornecedor_produto->produto`**

tenho meus modelos:

```
class Fornecedor extends Model{
    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class)
            ->using(FornecedorProduto::class);
    }
}
```

---

```
class Produto extends Model{
    public function fornecedores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Fornecedor::class)
            ->using(FornecedorProduto::class);
    }
}
```

---

```
class FornecedorProduto extends Pivot {}
```

minha dificuldade é que minha tabela `Pivot(fornecedor_produto)` tem 32 campos além dos `produto_id` e `fornecedor_id`;

Quando utilizo o `$fornecedor->produtos()->first()->pivot`, me retorna somente

```
#attributes: array:2 [
    "fornecedor_id" => 1
    "produto_id"    => 1
]
```

Tem como retornar os meus **32** outros campos sem colocar todos os campos no `withPivot([col1,col2,...,col32])` nos relacionamentos?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Relacionamento de Tabelas Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156143/relacionamento-de-tabelas-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tem como retornar os meus 32 outros campos sem colocar todos os campos no withPivot([col1,col2,...,col32]) nos relacionamentos?

A resposta que a documentação tem é **NÃO**, *ou seja*, todos os campos extras (adicionais) deveM ser explicitamente passados na relação como sugere no exemplo:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->using('App\RoleUser')
            ->withPivot([
                'created_by', // campo extra
                'updated_by', // campo extra
             ]);
```

<sup>Referencia do código: [Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)</sup>

ou separado por virgula:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1','column2');
```

<sup>Referencia do código: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)</sup>

Também é bom esclarecer que o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) e suas relações tirando a parte das convenções o resto tudo precisa ser configurado e a tabela `Pivot` quando sae da convenção precisa que os campos extras sejam declarados, para que `framework` [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) saiba o que precisa retornar e também no momento das operações de gravar e/ou alterar o que fazer.

Se fosse feito no modo tradicional não seria passados todos os campos? A resposta é sim, então segue o mesmo planejamento mesmo sendo um `ORM`.

Comment: obrigado pelo esclarecimento, achei que teria alguma trick para declarar esses campos no model pivot.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Fez voltas atoas, não precisa passar withPivot para o Created e Updated só se caso envolve mais dados.

Comment: Tomei um voto negativo por perseguição isso é claro.